# Testing meteor with FrisbyJS on Travis CI

Tags: meteor, travis-ci, jasmine-node

I'm attempting to use Travis-CI as a testrunner to test my simple meteor app

I want it to

- Install dependencies
- Run Meteor
- Run tests then return pass or fail

However, I can't get

- tests to run after meteor is ready to run
- jasmine node errors to indicate to travis CI that the build has failed

My travis.yml:

```
    language: node_js
        node_js:
          - "0.10"
    before_script:
      - "npm i -g jasmine-node"
    before_install:
      - "curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephfinlayson/travis-ci-laika/master/configure.sh | /bin/sh"
    services:
      - mongodb
```

I've stitched this together from various websites.

You can see an example of a recent build failure here. https://travis-ci.org/josephfinlayson/highscores/builds/26794570